# Need to call self.method in another method with ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, methods

## app/models/product.rb

```
    class Product < ApplicationRecord
      def methode1.1
        # Do something
      end
      def method1
        # Do something
        methode1.1
      end
      def self.method2
        # Do something
        method1
      end
    end
```

## in controller

```
def Method_4
  # Do something
  Product.method2
  # Do something
end
```

I call `method2` from controller. When I run the program. I got an error:

```
undefined local variable or method methode1 '' for class
```

Comment: What's the code in your controller?

Comment: @SebastianPalma please re check question i have updated it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call a class method `Product.method2` and it tries to call an instance method `method1`. In order to do that, you need to find or initialize an instance of a model, e.g.:

```
  # initialize
  def self.method2
    # Do something
    new.method1
  end
```

or

```
  # find
  def self.method2
    # Do something
    find_by(attr1: val1, attr2: val2).method1
  end
```